# Sorting dates that are nested inside a list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, insertion-sort

So I have a list that contains other lists inside it. These inner lists have a float id as their first element and a date as the second element. I wish to sort this list based on the date but making sure the respective id of that date stays with its respective date...

This is how  the original list looks like...

```
[[1.33315, '2020/07/22'],[1.33315, '2020/07/25'],[1.33315, '2020/07/27'],[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'],[1.345646, '2020/07/22'],[1.345646, '2020/07/25']]
```

I wish to sort it so its like

```
[[1.346646, '2020/07/21'],[1.345646, '2020/07/21'],[1.33315, '2020/07/22'],[1.345646, '2020/07/22'],[1.33315, '2020/07/25'],[1.345646, '2020/07/25'],[1.33315, '2020/07/27']]
```

I need the sort to be as quick as possible while also being simple. I tried using insertion sorting but it doesn't seem to work
Here is the code and `dates` is the variable that holds the previously mentioned list

```
def date_sort(self, dates):
    
    for i in range(1,len(dates)):
        items_to_insert = dates[i][1]
        print(items_to_insert)
        j = i - 1 
        
        y = datetime.strptime(dates[j][1],"%Y/%m/%d")
        z = datetime.strptime(items_to_insert,"%Y/%m/%d")
        while j >= 0 and y > z:
            dates[j+1] = dates[j]
            j-=1
            break
        else:
            dates[j+1][1] = items_to_insert
        
    print(dates)
```

This is the output I get...

```
[[1.33315, '2020/07/22'], [1.33315, '2020/07/25'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27']]
```

As you can see some of the values have completely changed. I do not understand what I am missing, or is there any better way to do this?Thanks!

Comment: Don't *implement sorting from scratch*, use the built-in `sorted`

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel with your own sorting algorithm, when you can just use the built in function, and give it a key: `sorted(my_list, key=lambda x:x[::-1])` should sort `my_list` with the last element (in this case, the date) taking priority. And since you have the dates as year/month/day, they should sort correctly. Do you want a solution specifically correcting your insertion sort algorithm, or is this sufficient?

Comment: oh thanks a lot... I didn't know you could do that...Thanks a lot :)...This is more than enough

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
lst.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[1], "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

One line lambda

```
xs = [[1.33315, '2020/07/22'],[1.33315, '2020/07/25'],[1.33315, '2020/07/27'],[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'],[1.345646, '2020/07/22'],[1.345646, '2020/07/25']]

print(sorted(xs, key=lambda x: x[1]))

## will give you 
## [[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'], [1.33315, '2020/07/22'], [1.345646, '2020/07/22'], [1.33315, '2020/07/25'], [1.345646, '2020/07/25'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sorted(iterable)` that returns sorted list or you can sort the list in-place using `list.sort()`.
Both the functions take `key` argument that tells the function what parameter to use for sorting.
In your case,

```
# Using sorted(iterable)
>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: x[1])
[[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'], [1.33315, '2020/07/22'], [1.345646, '2020/07/22'], [1.33315, '2020/07/25'], [1.345646, '2020/07/25'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27']]

# Using list.sort()
>>> xs = [[1.33315, '2020/07/22'],[1.33315, '2020/07/25'],[1.33315, '2020/07/27'],[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'],[1.345646, '2020/07/22'],[1.345646, '2020/07/25']]
>>> xs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> xs
[[1.346646, '2020/07/21'], [1.345646, '2020/07/21'], [1.33315, '2020/07/22'], [1.345646, '2020/07/22'], [1.33315, '2020/07/25'], [1.345646, '2020/07/25'], [1.33315, '2020/07/27']]
```